# dotnet.exe .NET Host from commandLine

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

When I run my webapi project in VSCode, it is hosted in  dotnet.exe .NET Host. Often the process is left open after closing VSCode. It it possible to communicate with it using commandLine?

Comment: Not really, cross process communication is generally forbidden. This condition usually happens when a resource is not released properly. The best resolution is to kill the process, and fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Thank you storm. Isn't .NET Host be a web server and running in its own process? IIS Express would be an example of a simular process but it has a command line interface.